# .NET Core (2.1) web API controller accepting all that follows within the request url as parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-routing, .net-core-2.1

What I have is a .NET Core 2.1 web API controller (in the following the TestController) that should generate redirects to other urls when receiving GET requests.

Example:

The controller is called like: http://localhost/api/v1/Test/somedir/somesubdir/filename.extension

and it should return a redirect to https://example-domain.com/somedir/somesubdir/filename.extension

My example controller for this question looks like:

```
  [Authorize]
  [Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
  public class TestController : ControllerBase
  {
    [HttpGet("{path}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string path)
    {
      //path e.g. is somedir/somesubdir/filename.extension
      string prefix = "https://example-domain.com/api/v1/Other/";
      //string path2 = HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Replace("/api/v1/Test/", "/api/v1/Other/").Replace("%2F", "/");
      return Redirect(prefix + path);
    }
  }
```

I don't get the routing to work. If I call the method with Swagger it get's called (with the slashes replaced by %2F) but at least it gets called.
If I call the controller via postman .NET Core just returns 404 Not Found.

I do not necessarily need the HttpGet("{path}"). I know that I could get the path like I assigned the path2 variable.

Any hints how I could get the routing right?

---

Another possible solution:

As pointed out by John and Kirk Larkin in the comments what I was looking for is a catch-all route filling the path argument with "somedir/somesubdir/filename.extension" independent how long the path afterwards is.

Just an asterisk in front of the variable name does the trick.

[HttpGet("{*path}")]

Comment: Don't quote me on this :) but I swear you could do something like `{*path}`.

Comment: @john post your comment as answer and I will accept it, it worked exactly like that HttpGet("{*path}")

Comment: It's called a *catch-all* route, if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I went to sleep immediately afterwards. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to take `"api/v1/Test"` into account as your code comments suggest, it is already filtered out by the [Route] attribute on the Controller level.

For the rest of the path that follows you can use **`{*path}`**:

```
[HttpGet("{*path}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string path)
{
    const string prefix = "https://example-domain.com/api/v1/Other/";
    return Redirect(prefix + path);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

@john, his solution is wonderful: `[HttpGet("{*path}")]`, just tested. but I want to keep my answer for feature use as an option:

as another option, you can follow MSDN [Catch-all route]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "blog",
  template: "Blog/{*article}", //<==
  defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "ReadArticle" });
```

> This template will match a URL path like
>   /Blog/All-About-Routing/Introduction and will extract the values {
>   controller = Blog, action = ReadArticle, article =
>   All-About-Routing/Introduction }. The default route values for
>   controller and action are produced by the route even though there are
>   no corresponding route parameters in the template. Default values can
>   be specified in the route template. The article route parameter is
>   defined as a catch-all by the appearance of an asterisk * before the
>   route parameter name. Catch-all route parameters capture the remainder
>   of the URL path, and can also match the empty string.

last options is: don't use controller, and do it in global configure:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.Map("api/v1/Test", x =>
        {
            x.Run(async context =>
            {
                //path e.g. is somedir/somesubdir/filename.extension
                string prefix = "https://example-domain.com/api/v1/Other/";
                string path = context.Request.Path.Value.Replace("/api/v1/Test/", "/api/v1/Other/").Replace("%2F", "/");
                context.Response.Redirect(prefix + path);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to receive those 3 params separated as you have in your URL, so.. that method should be something like this...

```
[Route("{dir}/{subdir}/filename")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string dir, string subdir, string filename)
{
  string path = dir + "/" + subdir + "/" + filename;
  //path e.g. is somedir/somesubdir/filename.extension
  string prefix = "https://example-domain.com/api/v1/Other/";
  //string path2 = HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Replace("/api/v1/Test/", "/api/v1/Other/").Replace("%2F", "/");
  return Redirect(prefix + path);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't do it that way since I do not know the incoming structure of path. It could be somedir/somesubdir/file.png or 15 subdirs before the filename

Comment: Then you need to receive all the path in one parameter, and encode the path segment of the url the same way Swagger is doing