# .NET Core (2.1) web API dynamic naming of routes to controller actions

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-routing, .net-core-2.1

I am in the need to use routes to API controller methods as prefixes for redirects.

I (of course) could hardcode them but I would prefer to get them dynamically so if I change the routing or controller names it gets updated by the logic.

```
  [Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
  public class TestController : ControllerBase
  {
    [HttpGet("{path}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string path)
    {
      string prefix = "api/v1/Other/"; //how to get that part dynamically?
      return Redirect(prefix + path);
    }
  }

  [Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
  public class OtherController : ControllerBase
  {
    [HttpGet("{path}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string path)
    {
    }
  }
```

How would I get the prefix in TestController as string dynamically updating if the Route annotation or the controller name changes?
I really need it at string.

Comment: if controller name can be changed, why not change this code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get the Route Data of the current request, change the name of the controller and generate an url with the updated new Route Data :

```
var routeData = this.HttpContext.GetRouteData();
routeData.Values["controller"] = "Other";
string url = Url.RouteUrl(routeData.Values);
return Redirect(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a [RedirectToActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.redirecttoactionresult?view=aspnetcore-2.1) instead of a [RedirectResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.redirectresult?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to redirect to a specific controller action by calling eg [RedirectToAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-2.1), eg :

```
return RedirectToAction("Other","OtherAction");
```

Or use [RedirectToRoute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoroute?view=aspnetcore-2.1) :

```
return RedirectToRoute(new {action="OtherAction",controller="Other"});
```

**Generating the URL**

The [URL Generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#url-generation) section in the [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1) article shows how to use `URL.Action` to generate the absolute link to another controller's action. From the example :

```
var url = Url.Action("Buy", "Products", new { id = 17, color = "red" });
return Content(url);
```

Adapting this to the question :

```
var url = Url.Action("OtherAction", "Other");
return Redirect(url);
```

`Url` is an instance of [IUrlHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iurlhelper?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Thanks for the input, it definitly would work like that in that scenario. But I really need it as string since I am populating response models holding those URLs. Thats why I can't use the RedirectMethods of the controllers.

Comment: In this case you can use one of the IUrlHelper methods to generate the link, as shown in [URL Generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#url-generation), eg `var url=Url.Action("OtherAction", "Other");`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos monty did not tell full story,  his another request is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615005/net-core-2-1-web-api-controller-accepting-all-that-follows-within-the-request/

Comment: Well, the full story is a complex controller doing a couple of things and i have two different problems there. But SO users/moderaters use to remind me too not ask two questions in one post.